# Aspx Web Forms Command argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I have a list of records. Each record has unique id and text. When I blow it on page, each record has a button, who refer to method `DeleteRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)`. But this button's doesn't know record's id. I tried push id on CommandArgument, but it's doesn't works.

Is there is another way to solve this trouble, or I simply make mistake, when I fill CommandArgument?

**Profile.aspx**:

```html
<%
foreach (DAL.Record record in records) 
{
    <b><% Response.Write(record.Text);%></b>
    <asp:Button CommandArgument="<%#Eval("record.Id")%>" runat="server" OnClick="DeleteRecord" />
}
%>
```

When I pause my program on **Profile.cs** in method:

```cs
protected void DeleteRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
    (Button)sender.CommandArgument 

    Always == "";
```

The problem in
`CommandArgument="<%#Eval("record.Id")%>"`, or my DNA.
Forgive me for my poor english.

Comment: CommandArgument='<%#Eval("record.Id")%>'  .single quotes. does this works?

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use inline scripts in server controls, that is:

```
<asp:Button CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument="<%#Eval("record.Id")%>" />
```

Is wrong, because you're trying to use server code in an attribute of a server control.

Instead of this, you either have to build the button manually (as an HTML control, not a server control), or you have to use a Repeater instead of foreach, and assign the CommandArgument in the repeater's ItemDataBound event handler.

Comment: Also, you can use `<%= record.Text %>` instead of `<% Response.Write(record.Text) %>`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4s0xktt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
Here is an example!

Answer (score 3):

You should probably bind to `OnCommand` event instead. It will give you `CommandEventArgs e` which has your property.

For more details, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.oncommand(v=vs.110).aspx.

EDIT:

An example follows:

```
private void DeleteRecord(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    var recordId = (string)e.CommandArgument;
    DatabaseModel.Delete(recordId);
}
```

In the aspx page:

```
<%
foreach (DAL.Record record in records) 
{
    <b><% Response.Write(record.Text);%></b>
    <asp:Button CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument="<%#Eval("record.Id")%>" runat="server" OnCommand="DeleteRecord" />
}
%>
```

If that doesn't help, make sure that the `DataBinding` event is fired for the control that contains data-binding expression, because for every such a control an event handler is generated of these expressions. This is because of `<%# %>` syntax.

Comment: It's doesn't matter, whether I use OnCommand or OnClick, because i didn't may fill CommandArgument corretly.
On msdn all CommandName"s" and CommandArgument"s" filled with magic strings, already known in advance for programmer. 
Anyway, thanks for trying help me.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Make sure you **really** check that DataBinding is fired

Answer (score -1):

```
<%
foreach (DAL.Record record in records) 
{
    <b><% Response.Write(record.Text);%></b>
    <asp:Button CommandArgument=**'**<%#Eval("record.Id")%>**'** runat="server" OnClick="DeleteRecord" />
}
%>
```